# Drag select in JList

Tags: java, selection, jlist

In the Swing `JFileChooser` you can select multiple files by clicking on the first file, holding down the mouse button and dragging.

Is it possible to enable this method of selecting multiple files in `JList` too? I have it set to `MULTIPLE_INTERVAL` so I can select multiple files by holding down shift, but dragging only selects one file.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: @Andrew For this one, I don't think an SSCCE is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JList does not directly support selection by dragging. Also, the file chooser does not seem to support selection by dragging either (at least in the metal or Windows look and feels) unless your are talking about the native file chooser on Windows (in Java 7 it supports multiple selection mode).

Selection by dragging has to be implemented by yourself with a mouse listener. See [here](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2008/10/using-rubber-band-selection-in-jlist.html) for an example that even shows a rubber band.

Comment: I am using Jfilechooser with native look and feel on Mac OS, I'll switch to the awt filechooser when Java 7 is released for mac. Thanks for the link